# Upgrade lumia 550 components

Tags: lumia-550

For £50, my lumia 550 runs well and is great and everything, but 1GB of RAM and 1.1GHz on a processor is not enough for my likes. I've always loved tinkering and was wondering if it was possible to upgrade the components of the phone, such as adding RAM, replacing/overclocking the processor etc.

What are my options? Can I do anything to increase the power of my phone? Or should I just save up for a better one?

Thanks for any help and if I need to be more specific on anything, do ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you are out of luck. All of the components are SMD mounted and while you can put the phone a part and locate the RAM module, there is no way to extract it and replace it safely and if in that case there would be no guarantee it would work.

Microsoft have slashed prices on the latest devices, I would recommend getting the 950, they are now very cheap.

Comment: Yes I have done some research and they are of exceptional value. I can get a 950xl for £340 and the spec suggests it is superior to an iPhone 7 and some of the new Android phones.